# error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token|

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following errors:

```
preprocessor_directives.cpp|15|error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token|
preprocessor_directives.cpp|26|error: expected `;' before "int"|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Avoid. Using #define for constants
#define MY_CONST1 1000

// Use. Equivalent constant definition
const int MY_CONST2 = 2000;

// Avoid. Using #define for function like macros
#define SQR1(x) (x*x)

// Use. Equivalent function definition
inline template <typename T>
T SQR2 ( T a ) {
    return a*a;
}
// Writing #define in multiple lines
#define MAX(a,b) \
((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

// Compile time flags
#define DEBUG

int main()
{
    cout << "SQR1 = " << SQR1(10) << endl;
    cout << "SQR2 = " << SQR2(10) << endl;
    cout << "MAX = " << MAX(10,11) << endl;
    cout << "MY_CONST1 = " << MY_CONST1 << endl;
    cout << "MY_CONST2 = " << MY_CONST2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is the inline template definition. why would you use the inline keyword here?

Comment: +1 for `Avoid. Using #define for ....`. Keep up the self-learning. By the way, also avoid macro for `MAX`.

Comment: I got it from this site http://login2win.blogspot.com/2008/06/c-preprocessor-directives.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the `inline` keyword after the `template` keyword.

```
template <typename T> inline
T SQR2 ( T a ) {
    return a*a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
template <typename T>
inline T SQR2 ( T a ) {
    return a*a;
}
```